# Canvas blurry text when scaling up

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating an app within a html5 canvas element that has a lot of text, buttons etc. I have set the initial size of the canvas to 1024 / 768 but I would like the app to scale up and fill all of the available space. When scaling the canvas up, the text elements become very Blurry.

I have tried doubling font size, then scaling it down to half the size which makes it slightly better but still blurry.

Is there anything that can be done about this or is canvas simply not well suited for this purpose?

I'm thinking it may have been better to overlay some dom elements.

Comment: An example snippet would be helpful. My guess is that you are scaling the canvas using CSS and not modifying the real canvas dimensions. Am I right?

Comment: I'm actually using a game framework called Phaser which is adding some inline styling to the canvas element to fill the maximum height whilst keeping the aspect ratio. It also sets the width and height attribs of the canvas element.

Comment: When you increase the width/height of the canvas using styling, you are just zooming in/out. So it blurs just like when you zoom on a photo.

Comment: Yeah this has just dawned on me, its just like stretching an image. This could get complicated to fix, unless I just switch to dom elements.

Comment: You may take a look at this : http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-scale-a-game-for-all-device-sizes-in-phaser/
A real scaling is possible but would require some work to get every elements to scale with the canvas.